# using of db.test.find(some_Query) in for loop is delaying in response, please suggest some mongodb query

Tags: mongodb, recursion, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection subcategory in which i store all subcategory of individual category , i can find easily, but problem arises when i store sub_subcategory of subcategory and the tree goes nested deeply, when i run the finding operation by recursion method , the response gets very slow like 2 min, here is the sample document
Document :

```
{
 _id : ObjectId('64787482945e164d1c590755'),
 name :"Fine Arts Animation",
 category :"Fine Arts",
 haveSubCategory :true,
 __v :0
}
```

and i am running this function :

Function :

```
 const getNestedSubCategory= async (req) => {
    let allSubCategory = await subCategory.find({ category: req }, { __v: 0 })
    let allMusic = []
    if (allSubCategory && allSubCategory.length) {
        for (i of allSubCategory) {
            if (i.haveSubCategory) {
                let name = i.name // must assign further it reflects the current value.
                let _id = i._id // must assign further it reflects the current value.

                let a = await this.getNestedSubCategory(i.name)
                let obj = { label: name, value: _id, children: a, key: i._id }
                allMusic.push(obj)

            } else {
                let obj = { label: i.name, value: i._id, children: [], key: i._id }
                allMusic.push(obj)
            }
        }
        return allMusic
    } else {
        return allMusic
    }
}
```

It returns the result ,
Result :

```
 {
            "label": "Fine Arts",
            "value": "64787411945e164d1c59073d",
            "children": [
                {
                    "label": "Fine Arts Animation",
                    "value": "64787482945e164d1c590755",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "label": "Fine Arts Animation 2D Vector",
                            "value": "6478754d945e164d1c59077d",
                            "children": [],
                            "key": "6478754d945e164d1c59077d"
                        },
                        {
                            "label": "Fine Arts Animation Hand-Drawn",
                            "value": "64787582945e164d1c590785",
                            "children": [],
                            "key": "64787582945e164d1c590785"
                        },
                    ],
                    "key": "6478795a945e164d1c5907ec"
                }
             }
```

and children goes deeply nested result whenever some document have haveSubcategory : true.. please suggest some query which runs inside db and return all the data, because query in db returns more faster.

I tried using recursion, i got the result , but in nested tree case it is very slow to find as i find using JS for loop, i am expecting any mongoDb query which runs in db and return i wish to get.

Comment: Perhaps using `$graphLookup` would improve execution time here by eliminating round trips over the network?

Comment: Could you provide a sample data set you have. Then would be able to help you creating an aggregation pipeline for this.

Comment: @imanshu15 https://mebook-work.s3.amazonaws.com/1686613583655-subcategories.json  hit this link , as i told it has only one collection which consist all the document you will find in this link, try extracting music, it is nested very deep.

Comment: @user20042973  could you please help me to make this, i have tried lot.